# Weak Law of Large Numbers (Non-convergence in probability)

Tags: convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Given $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ independent random variables with $P(X_n=4^n)=P(X_n=-4^n)=1/2$. Let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +... + X_n$. Determine for which $\epsilon>0$, if any, that the $P(|S_n|/n>\epsilon)$ does not converge to $0$. Why does this result not contradict with WLLN?

For the first part of the question, we can find that for all $\epsilon$, $P(|S_n|/n>\epsilon)$ does not converge to 0. However, I am not sure why does it not contradicting with WLLN, since $E(|X|)=4^n$ it cannot be finite... How can we proof it in this case?

Comment: Indeed the expectations do not converge, thus the conditions of the theorem do not hold, and so does its consequence. I think you did absolutely fine :)

Comment: Was just wondering if there's is another way to proof WLLN (maybe through implication of convergence modes) to show that it still holds... or if my assumption for the first part of question (non-convergence) was invalid...

Comment: Any $\epsilon >0$ will do. $|\frac {S_n} n|\ge [{4^{n}-(4+4^{2}+...+4^{n-1}})]/n \to \infty$.